# Why is my Vector2:new(ax, ay) function getting a table instead of a num value?

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm new to programming and learning LÖVE2D and LUA. I made a Vec2 module based on a tutorial but, when I use it, (for example `vec2 = Vector2:new(128,128)`), Vector2.x and Vector2.y get table values and I can't operate with them as nums. Is there a way to restrict the type of the arguments of Vector2:new() or am I doing something wrong? If I'm doing something outside the good practices correct it too please. Thanks!

file vector2.lua

```
return {
    new = function(ax, ay)
        local Vector2 = {
            x = ax or 0,
            y = ay or 0
        }

        function Vector2:move(a, b, dt)
            self.x = self.x + a * dt
            self.y = self.y + b * dt
        end

        --To see which values are the fields getting
        print(Vector2.x)
        print(Vector2.y)

        return Vector2
    end
}
```

What print(Vector2.x) returns is something like:

```
table: 0x0971d7d0
```

Comment: The only issue I see is that if `Vector2` is the result of `require`, then it shouldn't even be callable. Is that `vec2` assignment really as it appears in your code?

Comment: Replace `Vector2:new()` with `Vector2.new()`

Comment: @luther Sorry, no. I corrected it already: it's always been `vec2 = Vector2:new(128, 128)`.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I tried it but I'm getting the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, [Using Vector2](https://github.com/XanTheDragon/LOVE2D-Vector2#using-vector2):

Vector2s are created with a simple command:

```
local point = Vector2.new(x, y)
```

You cannot use `Vector2(x,y)` nor  `Vector:new(x,y)` as there are no respective definitons.

function call `Vector2:new(x,y)` is syntactic sugar for `Vector2(Vector2, x,y)` which in order to work requires a definition like

```
function Vector2:new(x,y)
  -- stuff
end
```

which is syntactic sugar for

```
function Vector2.new(self, x, y)
  -- stuff
end
```

Otherwise table `Vector2` will end up in `x` when you call `Vector2:new(x,y)`.

Refer to the Lua Reference manual for details on how to define and call functions.

Comment: Thank you all. Now I understand why wasn't it working. I've changed it already and it works know